# if SqlConnection C# Check Connection open , close

Tags: c

My code not want to return close connection.
I'm not able to use them if I do not have much knowledge.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = GetCString();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))


            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Open();
                Logger.getS().info_warning("Conexão Sucedida");
                Logger.getS().info_warning("DataSource : " + connection.DataSource);
                Logger.getS().info_warning("Banco De Dados : " + connection.Database);
                Logger.getS().info_warning("Versão do SQL : " + connection.ServerVersion);
                Logger.getS().info_warning("Status : " + connection.State);

                {

                }

            }
              else
              {

                  Logger.getS().info_erro("SqlConnection Não foi possivel connectar.");
                  Logger.getS().info_erro(" Status da Conexão : " + connection.State);


              }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new connection, initially it is always closed. Then, you need to open it. However, you check a connection for being open before opening it.

Thereafter, this condition will never be `true` in your case:

```
if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
```

Moreover, you don't need to check a connection for it's state. If connection fails, it will throw an exception. You can simply open a connection and be sure that it will either work properly or throw an exception.

It should be like:

```
try 
{
    string connectionString = GetCString();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        Logger.getS().info_warning("Conexão Sucedida");
        Logger.getS().info_warning("DataSource : " + connection.DataSource);
        Logger.getS().info_warning("Banco De Dados : " + connection.Database);
        Logger.getS().info_warning("Versão do SQL : " + connection.ServerVersion);
        Logger.getS().info_warning("Status : " + connection.State);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
    Logger.getS().info_error("SqlConnection Não foi possivel connectar.");
    Logger.getS().info_error("SqlConnection exception message: " + ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

*P.S.* You can implement your `info_error`, `info_warning` etc. as `(string message, params string[] args)` and use `String.Format`. It will probably be more convenient:

```
Logger.getS().info_warning("Versão do SQL: {0}", connection.ServerVersion);
```

Comment: @GuilhermeHenrique You have a connection string in your config file. There is a value `ConnectionTimeout`. If it is set to 10 seconds then it will wait a connection for 10 seconds, then assume that it is timed out and throw an error. You can assign a smaller value there.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="GetCString"
      connectionString="Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=Db_Tank;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>


no app.config :c

Comment: @GuilhermeHenrique It looks like 10 seconds is a default value. Try adding `;ConnectionTimeout=2` in the end of your `connectionString` after a `Password`.

Comment: connectionString="Data Source=*;Initial Catalog=Db_Tank;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Fnando@123 ;ConnectionTimeout=2"  ?